# JMeter - nested variables

Tags: jmeter

How can I properly reference loop counter `i` here?

```
log.info("Property of thread '" + ${__threadNum} + "' in tearDown is: " + ${__P(ah_${__threadNum},)});
log.info("Property of thread '" + 2 + "' in tearDown is: " + ${__P(ah_2,)});
vars.put("assertionResults", ${__P(ah_${__threadNum},)});
log.info("assertionResults = " + vars.get("assertionResults"));

// Loop
log.info("Loop is starting!");
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {  
    log.info("Property of thread '" + i + "' in tearDown is: " + ${__P(ah_i,)});
}
log.info("Loop is ending!");
```

The problem is in `${__P(ah_i,)}`. When I use `${__P(ah_2,)}`, it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts.

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as **caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So:

- instead of `${__threadNum}` - `ctx.getThreadNum()`
- instead of `${__P(ah_${__threadNum},)}` - `props.get('ah_' + ctx.getThreadNum())`
- etc.

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @Dmitri T for your answer! The finally solution that works for me is:

```
log.info("Property of thread '" + ${__threadNum} + "' in tearDown is: " + ${__P(ah_${__threadNum},)});
log.info("Property of thread '" + 2 + "' in tearDown is: " + ${__P(ah_2,)});
vars.put("assertionResults", ${__P(ah_${__threadNum},)});
log.info("assertionResults = " + vars.get("assertionResults"));

// Loop
log.info("Loop is starting!");
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {  
    log.info("Property of thread '" + i + "' in tearDown is: " + props.get("ah_" + (ctx.getThreadNum() + i)));
}
log.info("Loop is ending!");
```